# Error: The "(" character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot be included in name

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-word

When I am converting the word into XML this error is thrown using VB.NET:

> Error: The "(" character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot be included in name

How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: This question appears to answer itself: don't use the "(" character in the name.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around this issue.

Comment: @Cody Gray.Sir when i am converting the word file into xml this error is thrown out .it may be due to microsoft default error or conversion problem.I can't recognise this problem exactly

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense. The message is telling you want you can't use "(" characters in the name, so don't use them. Write code to replace those characters with something else.

Comment: When you try to export a Microsoft  catalog to XML, the resulting file cannot be imported, and you receive the following error message
"The XML file path/filename contains an error at line. " "A Name contained an invalid character."
If you validate the XML catalog by using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET  you receive the following error message:
"The '(' character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot begin a name. Line #, Position #"
This problem occurs because the Commerce Server export was not encoding the following special characters:

Comment: This problem occurs because the Commerce Server export was not encoding the following special characters:
The range 0x0021 – 0x002F includes ! “ # $ % & ‘ ( ) * + , - . /
The range 0x03A – 0x0040 includes : ; < = > ? @
The range 0x007B – 0x007E includes { | } ~
The range 0x005B – 0x005E [ \ ] ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to export a Microsoft catalog to XML, the resulting file cannot be imported, and you receive the following error message "The XML file path/filename contains an error at line. " "A Name contained an invalid character."

If you validate the XML catalog by using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET you receive the following error message:

"The '(' character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot begin a name. Line #, Position #"

This problem occurs because the Commerce Server export was not encoding the following special characters:

```
The range 0x0021 – 0x002F includes ! “ # $ % & ‘ ( ) * + , - . /
The range 0x03A – 0x0040 includes : ; < = > ? @
The range 0x007B – 0x007E includes { | } ~
The range 0x005B – 0x005E [ \ ] ^**
```